# In Git for Windows Bash, how to install "get-apt" and "sudo" and all those basic commands?

Tags: angularjs, git, bash

I was working mostly on Mac, so I have no idea about how to set up git environment on Windows 8.

Today, I was going to start AngularJS on my Windows Machine. On tutorial, I saw it requires git, and I downloaded the "Git for windows", called "MINGW64".

On tutorial, it asked me to use command:

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm
nodejs --version
npm --version
```

Then, the bash told me

```
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

I was confused and thought the apt-get is a pre-installed thing, so I changed the git setting and re-installed it with all different settings. It still the same.

And I am so surprised that "sudo" is not found as well.

Next, I searched online and had many vague answer which directs to the path, I think that might be the issue, but the person did not clearly say how to solve it. I was hoping can get some help from Stack overflow community how can I install the apt-get and other basic commands packages on git for windows.

If it is a duplicate, please guide me a bit how to use the correct words to mention this issue. I have tried "git for windows has no apt-get", etc on Google, and no luck for me. This has bothered me whole night. Thanks!

Link for [AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Link for [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win)

Comment: You can't. There is no such thing as apt-get for Windows, mainly because there are no software repositories for Windows apt-get could use. If you want to replicate a Linux environment on your Windows machine, install a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: As for sudo, there are some Windows equivalents, but you normally don't need it for developing software on Windows. Normally you only need sudo to install stuff, e.g. with apt-get, but there's no apt-get (see above).

Comment: Thank you, I see, so there is no way to create a shell that is similar to Linux shell. Got it.

Comment: A shell like bash is a program that is used to run other programs. Bash on windows is fairly similar to bash elsewhere, it's the other programs that are not the same.

Comment: The bash on Windows work announced at build this year does this.  It's actually the entire Ubuntu user mode.  Check it out before giving up :).  Docs here https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### Update

With WSL, It's now possible to run a complete Linux system, like Ubuntu, inside Windows. and one can install everything, including Node and Git there in the WSL Linux. Just like [Sarah Cooley pointed in the other answer from her](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652220/537554).

##### Pre-WSL Answer

If you want Node.js and npm on Windows, you can download them from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), `apt-get` is for Linux (Debian based). Here's a [guide](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows).

And [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) is a Windows based Git distribution, it's a separate project from Node.js, and it provides a limited set of linux-like CLI tools compiled natively for Windows.

If you setup `PATH` correctly, you can indeed run node commands in the Bash shell of Git for Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see, Linux system is much easier for developing anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The entire Ubuntu user mode (including BASH) now runs on Windows.  Apt-get node etc all work.  Check it out.  [Docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/about).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was having trouble with the git for windows, I guess it is just not apply on the app.