# How to install *.dev packages in windows if they are a prerequisite for another package?

Tags: python, windows, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo

I need to install python3.7-dev and libspatialindex-dev before setting up another private package in my Windows computer.

I have the instructions how to install in Linux (for example, see below):

 `sudo apt-get install -y libspatialindex-dev`

There are alternative methods that I have found with conda in Windows (see below):

 `conda install -c conda-forge libspatialindex=1.9.3`

I know that you can only get Linux commands like "sudo apt" via WSL or Chocolatey or like a linux virtual machine etc. ([In Git for Windows Bash, how to install "get-apt" and "sudo" and all those basic commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629058/in-git-for-windows-bash-how-to-install-get-apt-and-sudo-and-all-those-basic), https://superuser.com/questions/947220/how-to-install-packages-apt-get-install-in-windows) but I have also read that Windows doesn't require these '*.dev' packages because it comes with the alternative installation method as you see above. ([How to get python-dev for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448710/how-to-get-python-dev-for-windows))

Can someone explain to me whether I should set up WSL, Chocolatey etc. or whether the alternative method is okay? If the alternative method isn't right, which out of linux package installing software should I select as the easiest to set up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up WSL will most likely not get you to be able to set up a build workflow on windows.

Getting the `dev` version of a library means having the necessary header files additionally to the compiled libraries needed for linking to these libraries. To achieve this will be different for the specific library you are looking for.

Specific to your question however, since you mentioned that you have conda, the python headers should already reside in the `\include` folder in your anaconda folder and `python.dll` should be in the main folder.

The command

```
conda install -c conda-forge libspatialindex=1.9.3
```

installs the headers you need under `Library\include` in your anaconda folder. So by setting the include dirs in your build pipeline accordingly, you should be able to compile your program